# Get contents from radio button array in email

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a sendemail.php set up for sending me information from a form.

The way I have it set to send the information is with

```
$_POST['variable name']
```

I cant figure out how to show the choice of a radio button array in the email that is sent to me.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, all radio buttons in a group necessarily have the same name, to be grouped together. They should each be given a different value. For example, your HTML could look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender_male" />
    <label for="gender_male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender_female" />
    <label for="gender_female">Female</label>
```

Then on your sendemail.php, you look at the value of `$_POST['gender']`, which will be either "male" or "female", depending which one of the radio buttons they had selected.

Answer (score 0):

Every radio button has to have a value set. You get the value of the selected button with `$_POST['name of radio button']`.